# jQuery Post in a loop, crashing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a loop that each time, retrieves another pages' content via `$.post` and upon completion, does the next page, until an element on that page shows 0 results.

```
function scrapeIt() {
    $(".currentPage").html("Current Page: " + page);
    $.post("scrapePosts.aspx", { page: page, search: keyword }, function (data) {
        $(".status").html(data);
        if ($("#count").html() == "10") {
            scrapeIt();
        } else {
            alert("Stopping...");
        }
    });
    page++;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = 1;
    var keyword;
    var stillGettingResults = true;

    $("#go").click(function () { //Start Button
        keyword = $("#keyword").val(); // Textbox
        $(".status").html("Loading...");
        scrapeIt();
    });
});
```

The idea was for the `scrapeIt()` function to call itself again, but only when it has completed the post request. It seems to just freeze though.

Comment: I don't get it? Is it supposed to overwrite `$(".status")` each time? And where do you match for `$("#count")`? Is it some element inside `data`.

Comment: yes, count is the ID of a div inside data. That's just for a UI thing really. To see progress. Irrelevent to my problem really. Should have removed it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var page = 1` and `var keyword` should both be declared in global scope, otherwise they are `undefined` in `function scrapeIt()`.

Your page could appear to be freezing because no `page` or `keyword` is being sent as part of the post request, and the server may not understand the request.

Answer (score 0):

see [setTimeout()](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) `$.post` is not asynchronous i guess and constantly calling it will freeze the browser thread

Comment: I thought that if I only called the function again in the success part that it would only trigger once it has completed and therefore would just be carried out one at a time.

Comment: Do you think it would just be a case of guessing how long it would take to complete?

Comment: yes it is called only once but it keeps the main thread busy and dont let it do any UI update task, instead calling your method asynchronously will help unblock the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Because of recursion page is always zero.
You need to increment the page variable in the post callback not at the end of scrapeIt.

```
$.post("scrapePosts.aspx", { page: page, search: keyword }, function (data) {
        page++;
        $(".status").html(data);
        if ($("#count").html() == "10") {
            scrapeIt();
        } else {
            alert("Stopping...");
        }
```

Comment: I'd agree that it is better to increment `page` within the post callback, but I don't think it has an effect on the current code.

Comment: LOL Without this page will always be zero

Comment: I've done this it still freezes. Makes sense to have it there though.

Comment: @Ovidiu, provided `page` is declared in global scope, the `page++` at the end of the function will still do its job correctly.

Comment: I think you are getting the same page over and over from the browser cache. try appending a timestamp to the url.

Comment: @Ovidiu, it works just fine - `page` is just incremented out of turn. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLxMS/.

Comment: @Box It works perfectly in your example because setTimeout breaks the callstack and thus you do not have recursion.

Comment: @Ovidiu, ah I see where you're coming from. However, `$.post` is asynchronous and therefore behaves like the `setTimeout` example (the browser fires off the Ajax request, and moves on directly to the next statement).